# Print values in a PROC IML

Tags: sas

This is a [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SMhdLbrO9zPCkWFF9oYlq-UCGdKiDqAi/view?usp=sharing) that I am using.

```
data have;
input name $char17.; datalines;
Abdallah
Abou Hanna
Afonso
Angre
Audepart
Bah Aicha
Baudras
Berthelot
;
```

This consists of just one variable which has some names in it. I have to create a macro in SAS which I have named `RAN_NAMES`. I have to enter a `NUM` and then it will print that amount of names. The problem that I am facing is that I have to print the names using a macro variable '&NAME' using a `DO` loop in different lines. And with them I have to print the dates.

So I don't know how to create a macro character variable because inside IML only a matrix is returned.

```
%MACRO RAN_NAMES(NUM);
PROC IML;
    varnms = {"nom"};
    USE WORKK.NOMS;
    READ ALL VAR varnms INTO NAMES;
    CLOSE WORKK.NOMS;
    N = NROW(NAMES);
    IF &NUM. > N THEN DO; PRINT "Maximum number of names exceeded. You can enter more than 41"; ABORT; END;
    ELSE DO;
            SAM = SAMPLE(NAMES, &NUM.);
        END;
QUIT;
%MEND RAN_NAMES;
```

Comment: You're going to need more tags if you expect to get any attention for your question and the fact that it's already been 45 minutes...ouch!

Comment: "I have to" ... Is this a homework assignment ?  Why do you have to use `&NAME` ?  Regarding "have to print the dates"... Your data has no dates.  Why not code `PROC PRINT DATA=NAMES(obs=&NUM);`